# An introduction paper to Harmonic map heat flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Hi,
can somebody of you give me a link to an introduction paper to the Harmonic map heat flow?

Thank you and best regars
Florian M.

Answer (score 3):

Although it is not a paper, "Variational Problems in Geometry" by Seiki Nishikawa is a nice --and rather short-- book that includes basic information on harmonic maps and the flow in question.

Answer (score 0):

The 2006 Leiden MS thesis "[Harmonic map heat ﬂow](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~mvdschan/Scriptie.pdf)" by Martin Schans is quite approachable,
with lots of figures and calculations.  It is almost exclusively focussed on
on the mapping from the disk to the sphere, perhaps too specialized for your purposes. 
An unusual aspect is that the even-numbered pages form a flip-book animation(!) of some
numerical computations.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it. Is there maybe another paper?

Thank you and best regards
Florian M.